# How to add Product Custom Options for specific Product?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes, date

In Magento 2.4, I need to add "Date", "Time" fields for only One Product - That is Belongs to a Separate "Attribute Set" Called "Services".

How to add this programmatically?

Comment: Maybe you can check this post as reference https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/add-product-custom-option-programmatically-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

if you have an 2 separate attributes date and time then

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->setName('Product 1');
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setAttributeSetId(111111); // your attribute set id ex: 111111 
$product->setSku('pro_1');
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$product->setVisibility(4);
$product->setPrice(array(1));
$product->setImage('');
$product->setSmallImage('');
$product->setThumbnail('');
$product->setStockData(array(
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
    'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
    'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
    'qty' => 100 //qty
    )
);

$product->setDate('04/10/2023');
$product->setTime('22 10:13');

$product->save();
```

if you have only one attribute for date and time then

**$product->setDate('04/10/2023');
$product->setTime('22 10:13');**

replace to

**$product->setYourAttributeCode('04/10/2023 22:10:13');**